# Comparing objects between 2 nested arrays in Angularjs and display respective matching data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, jquery-mobile-collapsible

I'm having two arrays : first one is `empdata` holding `empid` and events attended by that employee, then second array is holding event details.

I need to compare `empid` from array with user input and display particular event details attended by respective employee using collapsible *jQuery*. Find total price also.

```
$scope.empdata=[];
$scope.data = [];

//first array data

   $scope.empdata.push({
    empid:'empid_1',
    events:[{
     event:'First Event'
    },
    {
      event:'Second Event'
    }
    ]})

    $scope.empdata.push({
     empid:'empid_2',
     events:[{
      event:'First Event'
    },
    {
      event:'Second Event'
    },
    {
     event:'Third Event'
    }]
     })

         //second array data
                $scope.data.push({
                    event:'First Event',
                    date: '10-jun-2015',
                    type:[{
                        name: 'Hotel Booking',
                        price: 400.00
                        },{
                        name: 'Flight',
                        price: 400.00       
                        },{
                        name: 'Honorarium',
                        price: 900.00       
                    }]
                })


                $scope.data.push({
                    event:'Second Event',
                    date: '27-july-2015',
                    type:[{
                        name: 'Hotel Booking',
                        price: 530.00
                        },{
                        name: 'Train',
                        price: 400.00       
                        },{
                        name: 'Honorarium',
                        price: 600.00   
                    }]
                })

                $scope.data.push({
                    event:'Third Event',
                    date: '20-aug-2015',

                    type:[{
                        name: 'Hotel Booking',
                        price: 910.00
                        },{
                        name: 'Flight',
                        price: 500.00       
                        },{
                        name: 'Honorarium',
                        price: 1500.00  
                    }]
                })
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: so you want to choose option from `$scope.empdata` and depending on that filter data in `$sope.data` ?

Comment: @Maven stop adding the questions inside quotes, stop adding code formatting for text, and stop adding unnecessary tags.

Comment: @Matsemann Okay with the questions part. I just did it after viewing couple of other posts. Agree. I could convert it into paragraph or so. Well, I thought of putting emphasis by using **bold** for the code part. But anyway, `empid` and `empdata` are part of code. It would indicate it is a variable or object or something being used in the code !! Wouldn't it ? Atleast for someone searching for something similar who wants to have a quick glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `custom filter` for this.

**[Custom Filter Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_09)**

see the below exmaple

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.filter('findobj', function() {
  return function(dataobj, selected) {
    return dataobj.filter(function(data) {
      return (selected || []).some(function(s) {
        return data.event === s.event;
      });
    });
  };
});
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.empdata = [];
  $scope.data = [];
  $scope.empdata.push({
    empid: 'empid_1',
    events: [{
      event: 'First Event'
    }, {
      event: 'Second Event'
    }]
  })



  $scope.empdata.push({
    empid: 'empid_2',
    events: [{
      event: 'First Event'
    }, {
      event: 'Second Event'
    }, {
      event: 'Third Event'
    }]
  })

  $scope.empdata.push({
    empid: 'empid_3',
    events: [{
      event: 'Forth Event'
    }, {
      event: 'Fifth Event'
    }]
  })

  //second array data
  $scope.data.push({
    event: 'First Event',
    date: '10-jun-2015',
    type: [{
      name: 'Hotel Booking',
      price: 400.00
    }, {
      name: 'Flight',
      price: 400.00
    }, {
      name: 'Honorarium',
      price: 900.00
    }]
  })


  $scope.data.push({
    event: 'Second Event',
    date: '27-july-2015',
    type: [{
      name: 'Hotel Booking',
      price: 530.00
    }, {
      name: 'Train',
      price: 400.00
    }, {
      name: 'Honorarium',
      price: 600.00
    }]
  })

  $scope.data.push({
    event: 'Forth Event',
    date: '27-july-2015',
    type: [{
      name: 'Hotel Booking',
      price: 530.00
    }, {
      name: 'Train',
      price: 400.00
    }, {
      name: 'Honorarium',
      price: 600.00
    }]
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select ng-options="emp.events as emp.empid for emp in empdata" ng-model="selected"></select>
    <hr/>Selected: {{selected}}
    <hr/>
    <div ng-repeat="d in data | findobj:selected  ">{{d}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```